# Windows XP AHCI

Tags: windows-xp, ahci

Is there Windows 7/Vista's MSAHCI.SYS driver ported for Windows XP because I don't know what AHCI driver is needed for my PC?

Please don't ask why I am using XP or upgrade my Windows version.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the Microsoft driver? Most SATA controller manufacturers already provide their own AHCI drivers for WinXP.

Comment: My notebook PC's intel driver does not support XP, I don't know what driver is used in my desktop PC, and my desktop PC has only AHCI.

Comment: So your hardware does not support XP. There is no reason to believe that a *core system* driver for Vista or 7 would work on Windows XP as interfaces methods may vary subtly. What have you tried so far? Have you tried anything? What were the results? What happened? You can [edit] your question to add additional details.

Comment: Yes, iaahci.sys(I don't know what to pick, picked anything ==> BSOD, http://alter.org.ua/soft/win/uni_ata too ==> BSOD

Answer (score 0):

I looked through both of my XP Machines (Virtual Machines). That file (driver) is not anywhere on either machine. The Windows 7 and Vista drivers are not likely at all to work. So I do not think you can modify your XP machine to use the AHCI drivers other than thos made for your machine.

There is an article here about enabling AHCI on your XP machine if it is there for the drive setup you have.  In the article just below "Steps to enable ..."  there are AHCI drivers you can try  (32-bit and 64-bit)

https://windowspro.eu/enable-ahci-without-reinstalling-windows-xp/